# Read Text file Line by line of different variables

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

How could I read this text file using Fortran?

```
V04hkaf

 2.00000E 01 

0.200 E 00   A_No axes 

 0.00300  

-0.6100       Modul D

 67.         


69.          dmq

 0.      

0.018        Beta area

 0.2012   

0.20716      d1 and d2

 100 

100 

100 

100 

100

 100 

100 

100 

100 

100

 57.00  E-06 

12.0   E-06  n5 n10

 885.0     

1.90000E 09  r5 1/ar

 0.0    E-08 

0.0    E-08  a38 a138

 3000.       

1460.0       dz dm

 60.         

10.          tE my

 3.00000E-07 

3.00000E-07  r1 r2

 1.2         

1.14         xv xq

         0  

.500E-03 

2.000E-03 

-.400E+09 

-.200E+09 

-.300E+09 Eigensp. 0:Lang 1:Vorgabe 

         1 

0.500E-03  

.700E+03  

.436E+03 

0.452E+00 

1.100E+00 HV
```

I only want to read the numbers not the text. When I try to read them by

```
OPEN (21,FILE=Eingabe)
READ (21,*) ITEXT,Alfa0ng,a,rmn,x1,z1,z2,Beta0g,bz,da1,da2
         READ (21,*) pxrr(1),pxrr(2),pxrr(3),pxrr(4),pxrr(5),pxrr(6)
          READ (21,*) pxrr(7),pxrr(8),pxrr(9),pxrr(10),Nyoel50,Nyoel100
           READ (21,*) Rho15,Kpmd,AlfaE38,AlfaE138,n1,t1,TetaoeC,Mym
            READ (21,*) rha1,rha2,xs,xca,iesp1,esp2,esp3,esp4,esp5,esp6
             READ (21,*) ifes1,fes2,fes3,fes4,fes5,fes6
```

I get

```
forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 21
```

Comment: Please show your complete compilable code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Read each line into a string with `write(*,'(A)') str`, then parse the string for numbers.